# Replace all characters after the 10th inside specific tag

Tags: regex, replace, innerhtml

I think I have the basics of this script but cant nail down why it isnt working. I have an anchor which is dynamic. Due to my design parameters if it is over 10 characters it is cut off, so I want to truncate it with a hellip after the 10th character. Iv written the Regex for it but need to impliment it. Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    var crumb = $('#breadcrumb > li > ul > li > a:first');
    console.log(crumb)
    crumb.innerHTML.replace(/^([\d\w\s]{10}).*?/,'$1&hellip;');
    console.log(crumb)
})
```

ignore the console.log lines as these are firebug scripts. For some reason my debugger returns crumbs correctly the first time but returns crumbs.innerHTML is undefined the second time. How do I get this to work?

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a regular expression.

Since you already have `innerHTML`, use the String methods and properties.

```
if (crumb.innerHTML.length > 10) {
   crumb.innerHTML = crumb.innerHTML.substr(0, 10) + '&hellip;';
}
```

#### UPDATE

See an example in action with [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9FRq/)

**Note:** If `innerHTML` has HTML markup, this solution will not work. That is I'm assuming there is only text within your anchor tags.

Comment: okay so iv amended your code a little to make it work this is what I have:

$(function() {

var crumb = $('#breadcrumb > li > ul > li > a:first').html();

console.log(crumb)
   
if (crumb.length > 10) {
   crumb = crumb.substr(0, 10) + '&hellip;';
}
    
// crumb.replace(/^([\d\w\s]{10}).*?/,'$1&hellip;');

console.log(crumb)


}
)

Comment: firebug returns it correctly but for some reason doesnt actually change my page.

Comment: See my update. Your example has a mix of vanilla JavaScript and what I assume is jQuery. This may be your issue. Let me know and I can adjust the code.

Comment: yes it does have a bit of a mix, got lots of librarys running. It is replacing content of the variable but now I need replace the content in:
$('#breadcrumb > li > ul > li > a:first').html() with my variable. Something like: crumb.html() = crumb;

Although that doesnt look right...

Comment: Try `crumb.html(new_string);` Where new_string is what I provided. You should avoid mixing and matching.

Comment: sorry I dont really understand? I have amended my code a little since last to target .text() instead of .HTML() just incase any unwanted tags appear. so at the moment my script takes my text turns it into crumb, replaces everything after the 10th character to a hellip but now I need to make my anchor display the resultant crumb, how do I do that?